# Error 404 not found : @types/escodegen@^0.0.2 while trying to install web-component-tester

Tags: npm, polymer, web-component-tester

In my project, we want to test our polymer components with web-component-tester.

So, I try to run the following command :

```
npm install web-component-tester --save
```

Every time, I get the following response : 404 Not Found: @types/escodegen@^0.0.2

I don't find this version of escodegen in the internet, do you know if a workaround exists to install web-component-tester?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Try by setting `npm-registry` using `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` command, remove `node_modules` directory, clear the `npm-cache` and then try to run `npm install web-component-tester --save` command.

Comment: Thank you, with this registry  the npm install has finished successfully. The problem came from our nexus which don't redirect to the registry npmjs when the dependency is not found

Comment: You're Welcome! In that case, you can hit an up arrow to my comment  :) LOL.